# How can I setup Jetty such that it is eqvuialent to Tomcat, supporting both JSP and Servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jetty

I had a Tomcat installation with a couple of webapps, and the intention is to use another JSP/Servlet engine, instead.  Jetty seems like a good fit.

I download Jetty 8 and started it up successfully, following the directions on the eclipse/jetty page.  But I'm a little lost as to how I could transfer over my webapps from Tomcat to Jetty.  I need to the ability to run both JSP and Servlets.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

JSPs and servlets can be packaged in a WAR the same way as they are packaged for Tomcat and deployed using `WebAppContext.setWar()`.

You can deploy multiple WAR files by repeated calls of `setWar`. This [blog](http://deepintojee.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/jetty-configuration-to-deploy-multiple-wars-in-integration-testing/) has more details.

Comment: Thank you.  Well, actually, I'm not even there yet.  I'm trying to understand what's the equivalent of server.xml and web.xml for the webapps.  But are you saying essentially all I have to do is take a war file and drop it inside the webapp directory of jetty?

Comment: Sure that will work. I use `setWar` for deploying specific files. For `server.xml` equivalent have at look at `$jetty.home/etc/jetty.xml`. Your `web.xml` files will be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll take a look at the jetty.xml file. One last question: JSP support in Jetty entails what exactly?  Tomcat sees a JSP page and knows what to do with it. For Jetty, is it the same?  Or, do the JSP files need to be compiled or processed in some way for Jetty to interpret JSP files or it works exactly the same as Tomcat?  Thank you.

Comment: Their usage wrt JSPs is _exactly_ the same. Just 'war' up & deploy. I've never done anything differently for JSPs for Jetty than Tomcat & I've used both products.

Comment: @user717236 You're overestimating this task. Everything inside your WAR files except context.xml is standard and works on both as-is.

Answer (score 1):

basically...copy the war file into the $jetty.home/webapps directory.

And since you need JSP support, look how to enable that here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP